# google play services not found on device

Tags: android

I'm an android newbie. I'm using android studio, device 4.0.4, api 14. When I run on device, I get the error message. It looks like google play services are missing on the device. I can see google play store on the device. I also activated using my gmail account. Device is not setup with verizon. Any help on what I'm missing?

```
09-23 10:16:44.642  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
09-23 10:16:45.263  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 W/SignInButton﹕ Sign in button not found, using placeholder instead
09-23 10:16:45.533  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
09-23 10:16:45.543  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 W/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ Google Play services is missing.
09-23 10:16:45.823  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
09-23 10:16:45.823  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ab0228)
09-23 10:16:45.823  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.noatta.www.noatta_14.LoginActivity.updateConnectButtonState(LoginActivity.java:250)
            at com.noatta.www.noatta_14.PlusBaseActivity.onConnectionFailed(PlusBaseActivity.java:264)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.id$g.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.ie.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.id$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ killProcess, pid=19251
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:788)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 D/Process﹕ dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 10:16:47.975  19251-19251/com.noatta.www.noatta_14 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 19251 SIG: 9
```

Manifest

```
<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.noatta.www.noatta_14" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
    <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Google Play Services != Google Play Store.

Comment: Thanks! I have a 4.0.4 and 2.6 devices. Neither seems to have google play services. Is there a minimum version number I need to look for. I believe 4.4 has google play services.

Comment: Do what is described here: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#ensure